# Connecting to SQL Server LocalDB in Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi, localdb, delphi-xe6

I have a `.mdf` database file, I want to connect to this file with `ADOConnection` and SQL Server LocalDB as provider

My connection string looks like this :

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDbFileName="MyMDFFileAddress";
```

But when I try to connect, this error is shown:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file "MDF File"
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file

I have tried many ways, but always the error above is shown!

I have Installed `SQLLocalDB` and SQL Server Native Client 11.0

On my machine I can connect to my own created instance on localDB and my database, but when I want to connect this file in another machine and use default instance and `AttachDbFileName`, that error is shown

I copied the `.mdf` file to default instance folder of LocalDB and tried to connect, but the same error is shown

I searched a lot but found no correct answer !

I'm using Delphi XE 6

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\"MyMDFFileAddress.mdf";Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Is there DataBase instance (v11.0) in another machine?
Open command prompt and type to verify:

```
sqllocaldb info
```